# Automate from Searchkit to Google Sheets or Office 365

Tags: searchkit, automation

Has anyone found a way to daily send results from a Searchkit result or table to Google Sheets or O365 spreadsheet? Is there a way to have Microsoft PowerAutomate or Zapier get the table? Is there a way to set it up to daily auto-send an email with the table attached? Seems that there are lots of possibilities to accomplish this.

Comment: An Export to Google Sheets extension would certainly be doable but I don't think it exists yet

Comment: Yes the automation possibilities from SearchKit seem pretty amazing. We are not there yet, but the day is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SearchKit shows you the API query it makes. You can take the query and use it in Google Apps Script in a Google Sheet with very little code. You can also set up an email with daily results directly in Google Apps Script.

Comment: I did get this to work. The end result does not really use SearchKit in any form since I just wrote a SQL query for the Google App Script. Thanks